# How can I make it to where if the value has been added then ignore the rest of the if statement?

Tags: vba, if-statement

How can I make it to where if the value has been added then ignore the rest of the if statement? I am running multiple if statements and need the coding to acknowledge when a value has already been used.

Comment: Post your current code. It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve from this description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893678/visual-basic-coding-issuei-can-send-you-a-sample-of-my-program-to-play-with 
here is my coding regarding another issue. I need it to go oh I already added that value I dont need to add it again

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a Boolean Flag to do this

1. Initialise the flag (by default it is False, but best to explicitly set this in case the variable scope is larger than the procedure)
2. Set the flag to True when a certain event happens (ie a cell is non-empty)
3. Check the flag during your code to test for early exit, executing different routines etc (such as leaving your IF logic)

   ```
   Sub SampleFlag()
   Dim bFlag As Boolean
   Dim lngCnt As Long
   bFlag = False
   For lngCnt = 1 To 10
   ' If any cell from A1 to A10 has a value then set flag to true
       If Len(Cells(lngCnt, 1)) > 0 Then bFlag = True
   ' Test for a true flag, then exit  
       If bFlag Then
           MsgBox "Cell " & Cells(lngCnt, 1).Address(0, 0) & " was not empty"
           Exit For
       End If
   Next
   ' if flag is false (ie not true) then no cell values were found
   If Not bFlag Then MsgBox "All cells were empty"
   End Sub
   ```